# Можно ли сократить код(csv)?

Tags: javascript

```
function arrayToCsv(data) {
  return data.map((arr) => {
    return arr.map((el) => {
      let str = '';
      if (typeof el === 'number') {
        str = el;
      } else if (typeof el === 'string') {
        str = `${el.replace(/"/g, '""')}`;
        if (/[,"]/.test(str)) {
          return `"${str}"`;
        }
      }
      return str;
    });
  }).join('\n');
}

// пример
console.log(arrayToCsv([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']])); // '1,2\na,b'
console.log(arrayToCsv([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d']])); // '1,2\n"a,b","c,d"'
```

Answer (score 4):

Стандартное приведение массива в строку уже содержит нужное поведение, единственное нужно вложенные строковые элементы обернуть в двойные кавычки при наличии запятой.

```js
function arrayToCsv(data) {
  return data.map((arr) => {
    return arr.map((el) => {
      el = `${el}`.includes(`"`) ? `${el.replaceAll('"', '""')}` : el;
      return `${el}`.includes(`,`) || `${el}`.includes(`"`) ? `"${el}"` : el;
    });
  }).join('\n');
}

// пример
console.log(arrayToCsv([[1, 2], ['a', 'b']])); // '1,2\na,b'
console.log(arrayToCsv([[1, 2], ['a,b', 'c,d']])); // '1,2\n"a,b","c,d"'
console.log(arrayToCsv([['"text"', 'other "long" text']])); // """text""","other ""long"" text"
```

Comment: а если у нас еще такой пример 
```console.log(arrayToCsv([['"text"', 'other "long" text']])); // """text""","other ""long"" text"```

Comment: @NurlanErgashev, там точно должен быть такой ответ, а не такой `""text"",other ""long"" text`? Удвоить кавычки можно, но в вашем примере непонятно, почему текст иногда оборачивается в кавычки, а иногда нет (почему не `'1,2\n"a","b"'` и `'1,2\n""a,b"",""c,d""'` в первом и втором, ведь это тоже строки)?

Comment: согласен с вами, но вот что выходит в тесте http://prntscr.com/uk1vfj

Comment: @NurlanErgashev дополнил ответ, добавив строчку на удвоение и одну на оборачивание в случае наличия запятой или двоеточий.

Comment: Спасибо @ Alex Krass